# How to store the image that was taken using camera in android to database using php

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have two buttons in the activity,One for getting camera and the other for uploading images to server.I have used volley to do this in android.It shows error as below

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2147
                                                                       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                           at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
                                                                           at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:132)
                                                                           at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
                                                                           at libcore.net.UriCodec.appendEncoded(UriCodec.java:119)
                                                                           at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:133)
                                                                           at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:450)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:436)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:260)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:234)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

when I click the upload button.Camera button is working fine.My android is as below:

Image.java

```
package com.login.sowmy.uspcar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Image extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnimgupload, btncamera;
    ImageView imgliccard;
    private String encoded_string, cust_name;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private File file;
    private Uri file_uri;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    SharedPreferences shared;
    final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
        imgliccard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imglic);
        btncamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncamera);
        btnimgupload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
        shared = getSharedPreferences("get", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        cust_name = shared.getString("key", null);
        btncamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                getFileUri();
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file_uri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

            }
        });
        btnimgupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Encode_image().execute();
            }
        });
    }



    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgliccard.setImageURI(file_uri);

        }
    }


    public void getFileUri() {
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) +
                File.separator + cust_name + ".jpg");
        file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    }

    public class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
            encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);
            System.out.print("Step 1" +encoded_string);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            makeRequest();
        }
    }


    private void makeRequest() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://localhost/img_upload1.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
                map.put("encoded_string",encoded_string);
                map.put("cust_name",cust_name);
                return map;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

My php file is as below

```
<?php
header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])) {
    $encoded_string=$_POST["encoded_string"];
    $cust_name=$_POST["cust_name"];
    $decoded_string =base64_decode($encoded_string);
    $path= 'android/'.$cust_name;

    $file=fopen($path,'wb');
    $is_written=fwrite($file,$decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if($is_written >0) {
        require 'connect.php';
        $query = "UPDATE cust_detail SET img_url=? WHERE cusname=? ";
        $params=array($path,$cust_name);
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$params);
        if( $result === false) {  
            echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";  
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
        } else {
            echo "success";
        }
    }
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
?>
```

I have added the following in manifest file

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have added volley as below in build gradle

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'.
```

Can anyone please help me to how to uploads images using volley with php script?

Comment: Are you testing in emulator or in real device ? Also must sure that data type of image (means in which format you are sending image e.g , byte  , Base64 or File) must be same for both back end and client side.

Comment: no I am testing in real device.I have used my ip address instead of localhost.yes I am using the same datatype.When I run the php separately using postman it worked .But while connecting to android ,there is no error message also

Comment: Log your _response_. What does it say?

Comment: `makeRequest()`. You are never calling that function. And the upload button merelycalls an asynctask which converts a file to an encoded string.

Comment: `I have used my ip addres`. Well the ip address of which device exactly? And you did not even tell where the webserver and your php script are running.

Comment: I hosted the php in IIS and ran the user registration in same app.I worked by connected db and storing data.But this image is not working..I have edited the code now as above by adding makerequest.Can you please help me in this.I am struck here for 2 days